.Net 7 How do I transform appsettings.json based on publish configuration
I'm using asp.net 7 with Visual Studio 2022 Professional. I develope web applications and publish these using either VS publish profiles or simple batch files. All I want the publish process to do, is build and copy the output to a specified path with the appropriate appsettings.json file.
I guess I am trying to do the equivalent of the old web.config transforms but with appsettings.json. I have different settings in my appsettings.Development.json than in my appsettings.json and I want the publish process to generate the appropriate appsettings.json based on my EnvironmentName variable.
I have tried the following in a batch file
dotnet publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:EnvironmentName=Development --output c:\temp -property:SatelliteResourceLanguages=en-US -r win-x64
pause

It does not work. It does indeed build and copy the output to the specified folder but the appsettings.json produced is not based on my appsettings.Development.json file. What I get is the original appsettings.json file unchaned.
Is it even possible to do transforms on appsettings.json based on EnvironmmentName?

You don't transform. There's nothing special about appsettings.json You can have multiple configuration sources with later ones overriding previous ones. WebHostBuilder already configures appsettings.json, an environment-specific file, environment variables and command-line arguments

The use of different configurations works differently in .NET Core.
Instead of producing a single configuration file, the choice of file is made by inspecting a variable that determines the environment.
From the documentation:

To determine the runtime environment, ASP.NET Core reads from the
following environment variables:

DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT when the
WebApplication.CreateBuilder method is called. The default ASP.NET
Core web app templates call WebApplication.CreateBuilder. The
DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT value overrides ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT when
WebApplicationBuilder is used. For other hosts, such as
ConfigureWebHostDefaults and WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder,
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT has higher precedence.

IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName can be set to any value, but the
following values are provided by the framework:

Development: The launchSettings.json file sets ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
to Development on the local machine.
Staging
Production: The default if DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT have not been set.


So, if your environment variable is Development, the appsettings.Development.json file will be used.
UPDATE:
To be clear and as Panagiotis has noted in the comments:
"The default HostBuilder setup always loads appsettings.json and then uses the env variable to load a file with overrides"
So the file chosen via the environment variable will be used to override the values of the base appsettings.json file.
(Thank you Panagiotis)
You can read more about it here.

That's wrong. The environment isn't used to select a specific settings file. The default HostBuilder setup always loads appsettings.json and then uses the env variable to load a file with overrides. After that it loads environment variables and command-line parameters

@PanagiotisKanavos semantics. "then uses the env variable to load a file with overrides" amounts to the same.

Not even close, and a lot of SO questions arise from this misunderstanding. You won't lose settings if you have empty appsettings.Production.json or appsettings.Development.json files. You can't remove an entire "section" by setting it to null or an empty string or array either. All sources (files, variables, parameters, database rows, configuration services) are shredded to key-value pairs and the last value per key wins

@PanagiotisKanavos giving this further thought, you are correct since it's not replacement but aggregation. I will update my answer. Thanks!
